# SQL Query Distinct Count Issue

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I am trying to get the count of models are under each manufacturer, in a table I want to display something like this:

```
Manufacturer       Models
Honda                7
Ford                 12
```

With models being for example, accord, civic, etc...

How exactly could I get that count? In the SQL table it is laid out like this

```
Manufacturer       Models
Honda              Accord
Honda              Civic
Ford               F150
Ford               Taurus
```

ETC....

In a table I want to lay it out like I have above....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query using [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177673.aspx) and [COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) with DISTINCT:

```
SELECT  Manufacturer
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT Models) as DistinctModels
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY Manufacturer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Manufacturer
     , count(*) total_models
from table
group by Manufacturer
order by Manufacturer
```

or for distinct

```
select Manufacturer
     , count(distinct Models) total_models
from table
group by Manufacturer
order by Manufacturer
```